# error 404 spring v2.3.2 when posting with ajax axios on tomcat 8 deployment

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, vue.js, thymeleaf

My spring application works well in my local machine and deploys successfully on tomcat 8 and 9 but when posting data with ajax via axios i am getting a 404 error messages, i have checked the url on both front-end and back-end and they are okay.

CONTROLLER

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
StudentSearchRepo studentSearchRepo;

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/csis/ajax/student/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public StudentSearch searchStudent(@RequestBody Student student)
{

    StudentSearch studentSearch = studentSearchRepo.findByStudentNumber(student.getStudentNumber());

    if(studentSearch == null)
    {
        StudentSearch studentSearch1 = new StudentSearch();
        studentSearch1.setApplicantNumber(1);
        return studentSearch1;
    }
    return studentSearch;

}
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

    new Vue({
        el: "#student_details",

        data:{
            studentNumber: '',
            search_content: false,
            result_set: false,
            student: []
        },



        methods:{

            searchStudent: function () {

                this.search_content = false;

                axios.post("/csis/ajax/student/search",{
                    studentNumber: this.studentNumber
                }).then(response =>{

                  

                     if(response.data.applicantNumber === 1)
                     {
                       
                         this.search_content = false;
                         this.result_set = true;

                     }else {
                         this.search_content = true;
                         this.result_set = false;
                         this.student = response.data
                      

                     }
                  
                }).catch( error =>{
                    console.log(error)
                })
            }

        }


    })
</script>
```

kindly help because i feel there is something i might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application might work well on an **Embedded Web Server** and not work as expected on an **external tomcat server** because on an external tomcat server the javascript method would be calling `localhost:8080/csis/ajax/student/search` but the **searchStudent** method would be accessible through `localhost:8080/{root-contextpath}/csis/ajax/student/search` and not `localhost:8080/csis/ajax/student/search`

To correct above ensure you have below line in your properties file

```
server.servlet.context-path=/csis
```

And change the value of @RequestMapping as below

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/ajax/student/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public StudentSearch searchStudent(@RequestBody Student student)
    {

        StudentSearch studentSearch = studentSearchRepo.findByStudentNumber(student.getStudentNumber());

        if(studentSearch == null)
        {
            StudentSearch studentSearch1 = new StudentSearch();
            studentSearch1.setApplicantNumber(1);
            return studentSearch1;
        }
        return studentSearch;

    }
```

> A key thing to note is:
>
> **Spring Boot Applications, by default, serves content on the root context path (“/”)**

Now, since it's a good idea to prefer convention over configuration, there are some cases where we really need to define our own custom path and you case is a perfect example.

**Also remember to set the Tomcat server dependency to provide and exclude it in some spring boot libraries as below:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- By @ASopia: Exclude the Tomcat dependency-->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```